# How to return value of an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, output

there I have a question. I am trying hard to do this without asking but after a couple of hours of searching and trying, I cannot seem to make it work. This is for an assignement. I just need guidance.

I have to create the following objects

```
Student(String name, double GPA)
Classroom (int maxClassSize)
```

The classroom object initializes an arrray where I would store the Student objects.

However, the array in Classroom() is declared as private (private Student students[]) so I  am adding students using a public method

```
public boolean add(Student aStudent)  *do not worry about the boolean type
```

I can also return the value of an array using a get method

```
public Student getStudent(int position)
```

Those methods are set in the assignment.

My question is, when I try to output the objects in the array (again, this is required for the assignment). I get the reference, ie Student@23e45e23 instead of the name and GPA of each object.

I cannot use toString.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to implement a toString method for Student, otherwise, it gives you a default one(the memoery address).

Comment: if you can access the student's properties you can do println getStudent(0).getName() + getStudent.getGPA();

Comment: I asked the teacher and I cannot use toString, and the assignment did specifically say "The proof output must be from objects returned to
your main method by the classroom object." (his words).

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing the (non-human friendly) output of the `toString()` method of the `Object` class.

Define a `toString()` method in your `Student` class, which will *override* the implementation found in the `Object` class (which `Student` implicitly extends)

Something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName + " - " gpa;
}
```

The `toString()` method is called whenever you print an object:

```
System.out.println(student);
```

if `student` is not null, this has the same effect as calling:

```
System.out.println(student.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to override toStringMethod()

Method1:

```
class Studet{
//
//
//
public String toString(){
 return name+""+GPA;
}
```

Method2:

make object of Class

and then access the values of variables using that object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it finally without using toString (can't use it) with

```
(student1.getName(classroom.getStudent(0))
```

and

```
(student1.getGPA(classroom.getStudent(0))
```

Thanks everyone!